# Postgres - wal files not getting deleted

Tags: postgresql

We have one master and two slaves and wal files are not getting deleted. I am new to the team and people are assuming they were getting deleted earlier and not any more.

But we found that we have wal file kept as long as Sep,2015.

Master:

```
archive_mode = off
archive_command = ''
```

slave1:

```
archive_cleanup_command -- not present on recovery_conf file
```

slave2:

```
archive_cleanup_command -- not present on recovery_conf file
```

wal logs are 600gb now and I have only couple of days before I delete those. Right now I am checking if basebackups are created so that I can delete wal files and resetxlog.

I am not understanding how wal files are generated when archive_mode is off. Can someone explain, what else to look for?

I will provide more information as needed.

Comment: Please add postgres version and the result of `select name,setting,unit from pg_settings where name like '%checkp%' or name like '%segment%' or name like '%wal%';`. Also, any relevant error in the server logs?

Comment: Hi Daniel Verite, Thanks for responding back. we are using postgres 9.3.                                                                                                                       We have one master and 2 slaves.

below is the archive_command on master.

archive_command = '/var/lib/PostgresPlus/9.3AS/scripts/archivWalFiles.sh %p %f PROD'  

From the script I could see that the wal files are archived to 2 locations on same drive. 
It is not the wal files that are getting piled up but the wal_archives.
Salves are not having any archive_cleanup command on recovery.conf file.

Comment: output from query you have asked me to check for:

             name             |   setting   | unit
------------------------------+-------------+------
 checkpoint_completion_target | 0.9         |
 checkpoint_segments          | 32          |
 checkpoint_timeout           | 300         | s
 checkpoint_warning           | 30          | s
 log_checkpoints              | off         |
 max_wal_senders              | 10          |

Comment: segment_size                 | 131072      | 8kB
 wal_block_size               | 8192        |
 wal_buffers                  | 2048        | 8kB
 wal_keep_segments            | 128         |
 wal_level                    | hot_standby |
 wal_receiver_status_interval | 10          | s
 wal_receiver_timeout         | 60000       | ms
 wal_segment_size             | 2048        | 8kB
 wal_sender_timeout           | 60000       | ms
 wal_sync_method              | fdatasync   |
 wal_writer_delay             | 200         | ms
(17 rows)

Comment: @Daniel Vérité 
I could not some how send my entire comment in one shot. and not able to properly format it. sorry for the trouble. I will check if i can format it in a better way for you.

Comment: you should move these infos into the question itself. Also you do have an archive_command in place so it completely changes the question anyway. You mention not having an archive_cleanup and it looks like it's exactly what you need.